# Moving circles elastic collision

Tags: java, collision-detection

I'm developing a very simple physical engine.
I have to calculate the final speed of a circle in an elastic collision against another circle. Each circle has a specific mass, radius and speed.

In order to calculate x and y speed I solve a system with conservation on momentum and conservation of kinetic energy equations.

By the way these equations don't consider the "shape" of circles.

So I calculate the rebound angle by finding the tangent where 2 circles intersect.

Now I have 2 different final speeds directions: the one calculated with momentum law and the one calculated with rebound.

I don't know how to combine the 2 speeds to get the final one

Comment: Sounds more like a physics question to me.

Comment: @Turing85 maybe... but it is related to a game engine, maybe someone can help me

Comment: Can you show, maybe in the context of code, what information you've already calculated and what you've tried please?

Comment: @Matt In my code I calculate the rebound angle (by finding the tangent in circles intersection point) and I apply the laws of conservation of momentum and kinetic energy in x and y direction in order to calculate the final speeds after the collision. My problem is to &quot;combine&quot; the two results I get. I&#39;ve tried to multiply them or to get the arithmetic avarage, but of course it doesn&#39;t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to consider normal and tangential components of my 2 circles velocities, and not their X and Y components. 
This way I can apply law of conservation of momentum related to tangent and normal, and at the same time it considers the geometry of circles too.

The last part of this tutorial is very helpful, even if I used a different algorithm, with some different logics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPzyNOHY3A4

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to calculate the speed in both the X and the Y direction.

Basically, what you do is calculate the results of the x component of the collision, the results of the collision in the y direction, and then combine them to find the resultant angles and speeds.

This is a common AP physics question, so you'll find lots of writeups on the internet about how to do it. This one looks like it should work for you:

http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys311.old/lectures/coll2d/coll2d.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've read the link you posted, but that is exactly what I'm doing in my code. My problem is to calculate the final direction based on the point of collision AND the law of conservation of momentum. I mean, if 2 balls collide and their centres lie on the same segment of their speed I have a result; but if their centres aren't on the same segment of the speeds then I have another result, even though their speeds are the same in the first and second case

Comment: You should use your two equations to calculate both the speed and the direction of both bodies in both the x and y directions. Then you can use some trigonometry to find the angle and speed they're travelling at. My advice would be to work through a few tutorials and solve some of these kinds of physics problems on paper. Once you understand that better, you can apply it to code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, these days I'll watch some tutorials. I'll let you know if I understand.

Comment: Perfect, I manage to make my engine work! I considered normal and tangential velocities, and not x and y components. This way I can apply law of conservation of momentum related to tangent and normal, and at the same time it considers the geometry of circles too. Thanks